# Angular Material input fields are not styled

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to use angular material in my project.
I've added `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css';` into my style.css file and it works fine - tables, cards, toolbars are styled properly, but forms are not.
I've used code from example [here](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples), just by copy and paste, and the outcome looks like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Here is my module (it is not main module):

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {ImageListComponent} from './image-list.component';
import {ImageListService} from './image-list.service';
import {FileSizePipe} from '../shared/file-size.pipe';
import {
  MdAutocompleteModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdCardModule,
  MdChipsModule,
  MdTableModule
} from '@angular/material';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {EnvironmentVariableComponent, ImageRunComponent} from './image-run.component';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { InputTestComponent } from './input-test.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdChipsModule,
    MdTableModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    MdAutocompleteModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ImageListComponent, FileSizePipe, ImageRunComponent, EnvironmentVariableComponent, InputTestComponent],
  providers: [ImageListService],
  exports: [ImageListComponent, ImageRunComponent, InputTestComponent]
})
export class ImageModule {
}
```

Here is my main module:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ImageModule} from './image/image.module';
import {MdToolbarModule} from "@angular/material";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ImageModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. My forms are not looking and behaving as it supposed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to import input and form-field modules in your module imports:

```
import {
    MdInputModule,
    MdFormFieldModule
} from '@angular/material';

// ....
imports: [
    MdInputModule,
    MdFormFieldModule,
],
```

Answer (score 13):

This can also happen because you didn't wrap your `<input matInput>` with a `<mat-form-field>`.

Comment: Thanks, but why is that happening? I would bet that I used matInputs before that weren't wrapped in mat-form-fields and they displayed just fine.

Comment: Directives can add classes, and if the classes are defined globally, then it's fine, but if there is encapsulation with the styles, then a component is needed to apply the styles. I forget how it's supposed to work in this case, but that could explain it.

Answer (score 2):

This question may be quite old, yet it remains prominent in Google searches. The answers provided were correct at the time, but the landscape has since evolved.

You can find the current API at the [offical source](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview). I'll highlight the most crucial elements necessary for applying the style to the fields.

Changes to **app.module.ts**. Make sure you provide the required **imports**, you can see, that the names of the modules have changed. They aren't **MdInputModule** etc. anymore. Here is a small example of the modules I am using in my **app.module.ts** adjust it to the components you want to use:

```
...
imports: [
    ...
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    FormsModule,
...
]
...
```

Add the default theme to your **style.scss**, adjust **indigo-pink** to whatever you want to use:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

The changes to the **style.scss** might not be required, if your angular.json has already this:

```
...
"styles": [
   "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
   "src/styles.scss"
],
...
```

Make sure to use the correct structure and right tags:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>My Label</mat-label>
  <input matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

In addition you can apply a default apperance in **app.module.ts** by adding a provider:

```
providers: [
    ...
    {provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {appearance: 'outline'}}
     ...
]
```

The injection token **MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS** opens some options for a global style configuration of your form fields. You can read more about it in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS)

I hope this helps.